# Why do OpenCV and Matplotlib force a delay when updating display?

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, real-time

Why do both OpenCV and Matplotlib require a call to a blocking function in order to update the display?

To display an image (say, 'i') in Matplotlib, typically you'd do something like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(i, cmap="gray")
plt.pause(0.001)
```

In OpenCV, you'd typically do:

```
import cv2 as cv
cv.imshow("image", i)
cv.waitKey(1)
```

In each case the final line calls a function that updates internals, handles events, *and blocks* for one millisecond (in my example - I think 1 ms is the smallest value you can pass).

Coming from a real-time embedded systems background, forcing a minimum block of 1 millisecond - of *any* amount - seems nonsensical. *Why do that?*

I fully understand that:

- The events need servicing and the internals need updating (so you have to call *something*)
- In most/many cases that will require at least 1 millisecond anyway
- 1 millisecond is a short enough time that it has little to no practical impact

Yet from a real-time perspective, any unnecessary block - even one millisecond - is normally something to avoid. Why slow down the program by even 1 ms if that's not necessary? It wastes time the thread could use for something else. Why isn't there a call that does all the necessary updating/event servicing and then returns immediately, rather than blocking?

(In fact the C++ interface for OpenCV has `cv::pollKey()` which does that, but it's not exported to Python.)

I assume the people who did OpenCV and Matplotlib had a good reason for this (I mean, two independent groups did the same thing). I assume they know what they're doing - I'm trying to not be arrogant and assume they're wrong, but can't figure out what the reason is for doing this.

What is the rationale behind this seemingly nonsensical design?

Comment: OpenCV's HighGUI module is a convenience tool -- good enough for a quick prototype. Having used matplotlib, and speed is definitely not it's strength. I'd say noone ever imagined either of those to be inside a real-time loop.

Comment: @DanMašek You're right, Matplotlib is hopelessly slow displaying images, but it's handy for displaying graphs that change in real time, and so the question remains - why do it that way? I assume the people who did it had a good reason, but can't figure out what it was. Re OpenCV, is there a faster way than using cv.imshow()? What?

Comment: You write your own UI code using a framework that suits your needs/requirements.

Comment: From my experience, most UI apps will spend most of their time in the message loop, especially if you want the UI responsive -- and there's really no need to update the screen in sub-millisecond intervals. And any serious number crunching gets offloaded to other threads.

Answer (score 2):

That is not how I typically display images.  Typically I do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(i)
plt.show()
```

```
>>> help(plt.show)
show(*, block=None)
    Display all open figures.
    
    In non-interactive mode, *block* defaults to True.  All figures
    will display and show will not return until all windows are closed.
    If there are no figures, return immediately.
    
    In interactive mode *block* defaults to False.  This will ensure
    that all of the figures are shown and this function immediately returns.
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    block : bool, optional
    
        If `True` block and run the GUI main loop until all windows
        are closed.
    
        If `False` ensure that all windows are displayed and return
        immediately.  In this case, you are responsible for ensuring
        that the event loop is running to have responsive figures.
    
    See Also
    --------
    ion : enable interactive mode
    ioff : disable interactive mode
```

But to answer your question, there's no alternative when it comes to waiting for an event.  The options are, (1) pass off control until an event is received, (2) pass off control for a specific duration of time, (3) never pass off control.

How else would you do it other than saying "how long do you want me to wait for events?"  It seems quite natural to me.  If your code can't currently spare the 1 millisecond, then don't spare it and call the update loop when you can.

Comment: This is correct.  https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/interactive_guide.html has lots more details.  If you want to flush the event loop in mpl you can do `fig.canvas.flush_events` which will clear ary UI events pending at the time of the call (but not any adding while servicing those events).

Comment: I'm totally confused by your answer, sorry. What's wrong with POLLING for events? No need to wait. Just ask " are there events pending?" If yes, service them. If not, go off and do something else - check again later. WHY is there a need to WAIT?? Somehow it seems I have a very different model of the world than you and the authors of Matplotlib and OpenCV. WHY would it EVER be a good idea to NEEDLESSLY WAIT (and waste thread cycles, even a few that will hardly be missed)? Obviously you "get it" and I don't - can you explain it to me?

Comment: Of course, I'm happy to.  In fact I find it rather interesting that you see it the way you do, and I'm trying to understand your perspective.  At any rate, *something* has to be servicing those events.  When you start a program, you get one thread and one process.  When the code you write calls a library function (like plt.imshow(), for example), that library code still runs in the context of *your* process and *your* thread -- which were created by the operating system when you initially executed the program.  So you seem to be asking, "why can't matplotlib and OpenCV not need a process?" (?)

Comment: @mmiron Thanks for trying; somehow we're not communicating well. I do fully understand that these libraries need a process and that the events need servicing. So some function needs to be called periodically to do that servicing. What I don't understand is why there needs to be an idle delay (1 ms or whatever) associated with that service function. Why can't the function just do it's servicing then return immediately? Why add the delay (even if small)? I really don't get it!

Comment: Well, as you can see in the docstring for `imshow()` above, it *does* provide you with the option of not waiting at all: make the call `plt.imshow(block=False)` and it'll do exactly what you're thinking is the "best" way of doing it.  If you want to see what a program looks like when it isn't servicing events, start a GUI program at the terminal and hit CTRL+Z in Linux.  Then click/move the window.  That's what programs look like when they aren't "waiting" for events.  Not a very good user experience: event driven code spends most of its time waiting for events/triggers anyway.  Make sense?

Comment: @mmrion - I think I see where you're coming from. But polling is just as good as waiting, and doesn't waste cycles.

Comment: But when you call `waitKey()`, internally `waitKey()` *is* polling.  It just saves your code the trouble of having to, and it includes a timeout.  Note, however, that I'm commenting from memory and have not checked the source code for OpenCV.

Comment: @mmiron But waitKey() gives no option to just poll once and not introduce a (minimum) 1 millisecond delay if there are no events pending. If you were able to poll it yourself, you could do something useful during that 1 millisecond. The designers of OpenCV included pollKey() for that purpose - but for some reason I still don't understand, whoever wrote the Python interface to OpenCV chose not to port that. I reluctantly conclude that those people simply "don't get" real time.

Comment: I do see your point, actually; I guess where I'm coming from is that checking for events a single time, to me, seems more wasteful than just yielding the CPU for a set amount of time.  But I do see your point.

Comment: I don't know any of the details, but if I were to guess, your answer isn't "I reluctantly conclude that those people simply 'don't get' real time." I expect it's a hack in an imperfect world. There is probably some underlying concurrency / synchronization need that isn't strictly guaranteed, perhaps because of lazy initialization, but will resolve on the 1st iteration if you block sufficiently long. The authors perhaps know there will be a pending event "very soon" after you call `imshow` and want to ensure it gets serviced now. If you can wait for regular event loop updates, use block=False.